# Cannot get SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2.0.24 working : Access to the path is denied on .cs file

Tags: msbuild, sonarqube

I'm trying to get sonarqube analysis to run along with the build (msbuild 12) on TFS 2013 using a VS2013 (.net 4.5.2) solution. I have already setup a SonarQube server and successfully ran manual scans.

I'm using tfvcTemplate.12.xaml with pre-compile and post-compile script pointing to sonarqube.scanner.msbuild.exe on the build server (d:\sonarqubeMSbuild..) with corresponding begin and end parameters. I have enable verbose mode to help understand the problem.

I always get the following error stack on the failed tfs build log :

```
    09:51:40.907 ERROR: Failed to analyze the file: D:\Builds\29\SD\ApplicationDemoTestsUnit_MAN\src\PreuvesDeConcept\TestsUnitaires\Application\CompteBancaire.cs
 09:51:40.907 ERROR: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'D:\Builds\29\SD\ApplicationDemoTestsUnit_MAN\src\PreuvesDeConcept\TestsUnitaires\Application\CompteBancaire.cs' is denied.
 09:51:40.907 ERROR:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 09:51:40.907 ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
 09:51:40.907 ERROR:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
 09:51:40.907 ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.CompilationHelper.GetSolutionFromFiles(String filePath, Encoding encoding, AnalyzerLanguage language)
 09:51:40.907 ERROR:    at SonarAnalyzer.Runner.Program.RunAnalysis(ScannerAnalyzerConfiguration conf)
 09:51:40.985 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: The .NET analyzer failed with exit code: 1 - Verify that the .NET Framework version 4.5.2 at least is installed.
```

File access error is verified on the build server using process monitor:

```
High Resolution Date & Time:    2017-01-04 09:51:40,9043151
Event Class:    File System
Operation:  CreateFile
Result: ACCESS DENIED
Path:   D:\Builds\29\SD\ApplicationDemoTestsUnit_MAN\src\PreuvesDeConcept\TestsUnitaires\Application\CompteBancaire.cs
TID:    5232
Duration:   0.0000914
Desired Access: Generic Read/Write
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File, Open No Recall
Attributes: n/a
ShareMode:  None
AllocationSize: n/a
```

The identity trying to access the file is the domain service account my build agent runs under. This account has full access to file system and is administrator on the build machine.

Any ideas on this matter would be highly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: We request Read/Write access to files, which is a mistake on our side. Here's the corresponding ticket to fix it: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1122. However I'm not sure that will fix your issues. `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown in many cases, and the ticket only fixes one. You might face another. Could you check if your file is readonly?

Comment: Tamas, you are right files are read-only, coming from source control the build agent perform a get latest and everything comes down as "read-only" on the build server's filesystem. Thanks! I'll try to bypass that to see if it helps. shouldn't everyone using scanner for msbuild run into this issue on automated builds?

Comment: We'll fix the ticket soon. Nobody reported this issue before, so I don't think everyone is affected. Also, note that this problem only affects msbuild12 builds, with msbuild14 we're not reading the files ourselves.

Comment: Let me know if marking the files non-readonly solves the issue or not.

Comment: It does! Thank you

Comment: Great, adding this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We request Read/Write access to files, which is a mistake on our side. Here's the corresponding ticket to fix it: https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SLVS-1122.